# Not able to pass value between forms ( maybe because of the Div element in form) in ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am not able to pass value between forms ( maybe because of the Div element in form) in ASP

My first file's code:

```
<form method=POST>
<div id="containerSB2" style="display:block;color:#0000FF">
<SELECT id=text2 name=text2  disabled style="WIDTH: 450px"> 
<option value="1" selected>One</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" Value="Submit Button" onclick="this.form.action='GS_Ajax_test_1.asp'"><br>
</form>
```

2nd file's code:

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<%
Room_Number= Request.Form("text2")
Response.write Room_Number+"hi"
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I ma not able to access value in text2...
Any help?

Comment: is the missing `<` in `form method=POST>` a typo?

Comment: Yes its a typo...when i removed 'disabled' then its working fine...But the new problem is I ma changing the innerHTML of this div tag using Ajax (New inner HTML also has 'select' element)...then it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Take the `disabled` off your select item.
It'll work.